# BeautifulSoup4: Find elements with children tags

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I am building a program to scrape webpages.

I need to find all `tr` elements in a page that have `td` children with `class="table"`

```
<tr>
    <td class="table">1</td>
    <td class="table">
        <a href="...">...</a>
    </td>
    <td class="table">18</td>
</tr>
```

I already managed to find all `td` with `class=table` elements with

```
MySoup = soup.find_all("td", { "class" : "table" })
```

and also all `tr`

```
MySoup = soup.find_all("tr")
```

but there are too many in the whole page, and this is not exactly what I need anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to find in a page all tr elements that have td children with class="table"

```
soup.select('tr td.table')
```

> If you want all td's which are direct childrens of `tr` then use

```
soup.select('tr > td.table')
```

Example:

```
>>> html = '''<tr>
    <td class="table">1</td>
    <td class="table">
        <a href="...">...</a>
    </td>
    <td class="table">18</td>
</tr><td class="table">19</td>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> soup.select('tr td.table')
[<td class="table">1</td>, <td class="table">\n<a href="...">...</a>\n</td>, <td class="table">18</td>]
>>>
```

Comment: `soup.select('tr td.table')` does not make the selection, as I am seeing the whole source in the result (not just the `tr`with children `td`).

Comment: because the whole source is present inside a tr.